# MS Bot Framework - Form Flow - Keep nice box with links formatting when using FieldReflector

Tags: botframework, formflow

So I am using FieldReflector to dynamically populate choices in a form flow and this works great. The problem is the non-dynamic enum fields show a very nice sort of "card" with links the user can click on. The fields I use FieldReflector revert to an ugly text list of choices like:

Select a topic choice (1. TopicA, 2. TopicB, or 3. TopicC)

Where did all the nice formatting go? I have gone round and round in the Templates and pattern documents trying so many things with no results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of the bot builder SDK are you using?

Comment: The problem was due to the type of the form-flow field. For some reason when it changed from enum it was made a List<string>. When I changed it just to string it worked fine.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working!